# Default volume level when recording video android

Tags: android, android-camera, volume

I want to know which volume level does it take when I record video using custom camera. I muted all my sounds and then record video but still I am getting voice in my recorded video(with custom camera). So that means its taking volume level not from phone's settings. Then how its doing that ? And can I increase the volume level when recording video with my custom camera ? I have searched about it and found that the following code can help:

```
AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);                  
mgr.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
```

But that code is having no effect. Whether I have this code or not, its taking the voice of same level.